# NativeScript Vue - Only render items in viewport on the list

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a template

```
<template>
<Page>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <RouteInfo
                v-for="route in fakeData"
                :key="route.key"
                :route="route" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
</template>
```

The `RouteInfo` component is fairly complicated and has multiple components within it. NativeScript seems to be rendering the **entire list**, even if it's not in the viewport. This is a huge performance hit especially with "large" lists, as it renders out everything first, then displays the list. How can I force it to only render what is in the viewport?

Comment: Using the NativeScript components `ListView` or `RadListView` will accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ListView](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/) instead. Use the built-in "for" loop in ListView just like in the example instead of using "v-for". It's more Native-ish.